# How the glycogen accumulate intracellularly in the reversible cell injury?

Tags: biochemistry, cell-biology, pathology

As we know in reversible cell injury as the most common cause is ischemia decreases oxidative phosphorylation which decrease ATP & increase anaerobic glycolysis which depleting glycogen !!? But one of the intracellular accumulation in addition to lipid , hyaline, pigments and calcium is glycogen So how this occurs ?